PostgreSQL regrouping after a generate_series while joining diferent tables with possible null values
In my database I have various tables with a primary_key, start_date and end_date
I'm trying to make a view table joining some of these periods so I can send this table to a PowerBI and use it.
My problem here is that these tables come with many different shapes, so I'm using the generate series method to expand it, then joining the other tables to the primary one with the columns I want.
I'm having trouble regrouping this table back to the start_date and end_date format. Because some tables leave null values and these end up grouping together even if they skip some dates:
for example:
| id_employe   | id_function | date
-
| 1            |       null  |  1  
| 1            |       null  |  2  
| 1            |         3   |  3  
| 1            |         3   |  4  
| 1            |         3   |  5  
| 1            |       null  |  6  
| 1            |       null  |  7

How can I group these effectively into:
| id_employe   | id_function    | start_date   | end_date  
| 1            |       null     |  1           |    2
| 1            |       3        |  3           |    4
| 1            |       null     |  5           |    7

And how can I do this if I have 6 different columns creating nulls in my query?
What method can I use to regroup after a generate_series that can account correctly for start and end dates?

May be (| 1            |       3        |  3           |    4) --> (| 1            |       3        |  3           |    5) ?

You can identify the groupings using a window function and then add the grouping number (island in my example) in with the group by columns:
with deltas as (
  select *, 
         (id_function is distinct from lag(id_function) over w)::int as delta
    from intab
  window w as (partition by id_employe order by ddate)
), islands as (
  select *, sum(delta) over w as island
    from deltas
  window w as (partition by id_employe order by ddate)
)
select id_employe, id_function, min(ddate) as start_date, max(ddate) as end_date
  from islands
 group by id_employe, island, id_function
 order by start_date;

dbfiddle
